# Best practise to initialize the same elements accross many Activities?

Tags: android, android-layout

My app has the footer part which consist of 5 icons. These icons are purely links to other activities.

Now, all screens must have this footer. Because of that I have to do repetitive tasks in each `activity`, such as initialization, registering `onClick` event, handling `onClick` event for each image, etc.

Is there a way to do all these tasks once and then to apply them to each activity? Just like I can make some XML layout and import it into any other XML layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already know `<include>`'s and `<merge>`'s

1. Create a class (we'll call it BergnamActivity) that extends `Activity`
2. In BergnamActivity, create `public void something*(View view)` methods that correspond to your Buttons.
3. In your footer layout (assuming you already used ), set the buttons' `onClick` to correspond to each of the methods in your BergnamActivity. You need to specify the method name, case sensitive. (For ex., `public void mainMethod(View view)` will result in an `android:onClick="mainMethod"`
4. For your normal activities, instead of extending activity, extend BergnamActivity

Ultimately, I'm against the idea of a common footer for android - that only works for iPhone apps, since there's only one physical button to control everything. Android has the Menu button that can bring up additional options for the user. The screen size will be much better utilized.

Comment: Thanks. I also agree on the last point, but I am implementing the logic on someone else's UI so I cannot change that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<include>` or `<merge>` to re-use the common layout file, then either create a small class to do the initialization for you and re-use that in all your activities, or subclass your activities from a common superclass that contains the initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

The **Android platform** offers a wide variety of UI widgets, small visual construction blocks that you can glue together to present users with complex and useful interfaces. However applications often need higher-level visual components. To meet that need, and to do so efficiently, you can combine multiple standard widgets into a single, reusable component.

You can use `<merge />` and `<include />` tags in your layout xml file for reuse layout in other layouts..

For more info look at [Layout Tricks: Creating Reusable UI Components](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html)

Comment: the link throws a 404